# Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command 'adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk' timed out after 60000ms'

Tags: java, android, linux, appium, adb

When I run the UI autotest, I keep getting an error: "Error executing adbExec", on various adb commands.
I will be glad for any help!
(Attached logs of one of the errors from appium server)

```
[Appium] Welcome to Appium v1.22.3
[Appium] Non-default server args:
[Appium]   port: 4724
[Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4724
[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/status
[HTTP] {}
[debug] [GENERIC] Calling AppiumDriver.getStatus() with args: []
[debug] [GENERIC] Responding to client with driver.getStatus() result: {"build":{"version":"1.22.3"}}
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 10 ms - 68
[HTTP]
[debug] [HTTP] Request idempotency key: 139d89ca-1ba4-4fca-b461-e4e84d24e12c
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session
[HTTP] {"capabilities":{"firstMatch":[{}],"alwaysMatch":{"appium:adbExecTimeout":60000,"appium:app":"/home/user/workspace/ui-tests/src/test/java/app/test.apk","appium:appPackage":"org.test.debug_test","appium:automationName":"UIAutomator2","appium:deviceName":"Pixel 3 API 31","appium:eventTimings":true,"appium:noReset":true,"appium:platformVersion":"12","appium:skipUnlock":true,"appium:udid":"emulator-5554","platformName":"android"}}}
[debug] [W3C] Calling AppiumDriver.createSession() with args: [null,null,{"firstMatch":[{}],"alwaysMatch":{"appium:adbExecTimeout":60000,"appium:app":"/home/user/workspace/ui-tests/src/test/java/app/test.apk","appium:appPackage":"org.test.debug_test","appium:automationName":"UIAutomator2","appium:deviceName":"Pixel 3 API 31","appium:eventTimings":true,"appium:noReset":true,"appium:platformVersion":"12","appium:skipUnlock":true,"appium:udid":"emulator-5554","platformName":"android"}}]
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionRequested' logged at 1673453270062 (19:07:50 GMT+0300 (Moscow Standard Time))
[Appium] Appium v1.22.3 creating new AndroidUiautomator2Driver (v1.70.1) session
[debug] [BaseDriver] Creating session with W3C capabilities: {
[debug] [BaseDriver]   "alwaysMatch": {
[debug] [BaseDriver]     "platformName": "android",
[debug] [BaseDriver]     "appium:adbExecTimeout": 60000,
[debug] [BaseDriver]     "appium:app": "/home/user/workspace/ui-tests/src/test/java/app/test.apk",
[debug] [BaseDriver]     "appium:appPackage": "org.test.debug_test",
[debug] [BaseDriver]     "appium:automationName": "UIAutomator2",
[debug] [BaseDriver]     "appium:deviceName": "Pixel 3 API 31",
[debug] [BaseDriver]     "appium:eventTimings": true,
[debug] [BaseDriver]     "appium:noReset": true,
[debug] [BaseDriver]     "appium:platformVersion": "12",
[debug] [BaseDriver]     "appium:skipUnlock": true,
[debug] [BaseDriver]     "appium:udid": "emulator-5554"
[debug] [BaseDriver]   },
[debug] [BaseDriver]   "firstMatch": [
[debug] [BaseDriver]     {}
[debug] [BaseDriver]   ]
[debug] [BaseDriver] }
[BaseDriver] Session created with session id: 355f9950-3bad-4c19-a44a-1770b3280b2b
[BaseDriver] Using local app '/home/user/workspace/ui-tests/src/test/java/app/test.apk'
[debug] [UiAutomator2] Checking whether app is actually present
[ADB] Found 2 'build-tools' folders under '/home/user/dev/Android/Sdk' (newest first):
[ADB]     /home/user/dev/Android/Sdk/build-tools/33.0.1
[ADB]     /home/user/dev/Android/Sdk/build-tools/30.0.3
[ADB] Using 'adb' from '/home/user/dev/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb'
[debug] [ADB] Running '/home/user/dev/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 start-server'
[AndroidDriver] Retrieving device list
[debug] [ADB] Trying to find a connected android device
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices
[debug] [ADB] Connected devices: [{"udid":"emulator-5554","state":"device"}]
[AndroidDriver] Using device: emulator-5554
[ADB] Using 'adb' from '/home/user/dev/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb'
[debug] [ADB] Running '/home/user/dev/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 start-server'
[debug] [ADB] Setting device id to emulator-5554
[debug] [ADB] Running '/home/user/dev/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk'
[debug] [UiAutomator2] Deleting UiAutomator2 session
[debug] [ADB] Running '/home/user/dev/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell am force-stop org.test.debug_test'
[UiAutomator2] Unable to force stop app: Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command '/home/user/dev/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell am force-stop org.test.debug_test' timed out after 60000ms'. Try to increase the 60000ms adb execution timeout represented by 'adbExecTimeout' capability
[debug] [ADB] Running '/home/user/dev/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk'
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1673453450427 (19:10:50 GMT+0300 (Moscow Standard Time))
[debug] [W3C] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Error getting device API level. Original error: Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command '/home/user/dev/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk' timed out after 60000ms'. Try to increase the 60000ms adb execution timeout represented by 'adbExecTimeout' capability
[debug] [W3C]     at ADB.getApiLevel (/usr/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-adb/lib/tools/adb-commands.js:159:13)
[debug] [W3C]     at AndroidUiautomator2Driver.deleteSession (/usr/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiautomator2-driver/lib/driver.js:671:11)
[debug] [W3C]     at AndroidUiautomator2Driver.createSession (/usr/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiautomator2-driver/lib/driver.js:238:7)
[debug] [W3C]     at AppiumDriver.createSession (/usr/lib/node_modules/appium/lib/appium.js:387:35)
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 180448 ms - 1145
[HTTP]
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 229.336 s <<< FAILURE! - in org.ui.tests.JustTest
[ERROR] org.ui.tests.JustTest  Time elapsed: 229.332 s  <<< ERROR!
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException:
Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Error getting device API level. Original error: Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command '/home/user/dev/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk' timed out after 60000ms'. Try to increase the 60000ms adb execution timeout represented by 'adbExecTimeout' capability
Build info: version: '4.7.2', revision: '4d4020c3b7'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.4.0-136-generic', java.version: '11.0.17'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[{appium:noReset=true, appium:udid=emulator-5554, appium:adbExecTimeout=60000, appium:eventTimings=true, appium:skipUnlock=true, appium:deviceName=Pixel 3 API 31, platformName=ANDROID, appium:automationName=UIAutomator2, appium:app=/home/user/workspace/ui-tests/src/test/java/app/test.apk, appium:platformVersion=12, appium:appPackage=org.test.debug_test}], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {appium:adbExecTimeout: 60000, appium:app: /home/user/workspace/..., appium:appPackage: org.test.debug_test, appium:automationName: UIAutomator2, appium:deviceName: Pixel 3 API 31, appium:eventTimings: true, appium:noReset: true, appium:platformVersion: 12, appium:skipUnlock: true, appium:udid: emulator-5554, platformName: ANDROID}}]
Capabilities {}
        at org.ui.tests.JustTest.setUp(JustTest.java:33)
```

Tried different adb (33.0.2, 33.0.3, 28.0.2) versions and different emulators API (28, 29, 30, 31) versions, but nothing helped I just keep getting an errors.
On local Windows machine tests run successfully, error reproduced on Linux VM with kvm enabled

Answer (score 0):

As a result, the problem was in the VM settings and, unfortunately, it was not possible to overcome this problem, it was decided to run tests on a physical machine as a separate agent on team city(
Good luck with testing!)